# JNA  library, missing Windows function: how to add new functions?

Tags: java, windows, dll, jna

i've a question about Java and `jna` library. I've downloaded the two jar (`jna.jar` and `platform.jar`) from java.net.

In the package `com.sun.jna.platform.win32` there are already some defined interfaces that link the win dll, but in the `Kernel32` file, a function is missing, the function is `DeviceIoControl`.

My questions are:

1. where can i find a complete list of all windows dll with a complete list of all functions, and possibly with a compatibily list with all of windows versions? (very important)
   From msdn site i've found the complete function list with the name of the library where the functions are contained, but not the other.
2. Can i create a new interface that extends Kernel32, so i can add the missing functions?
   Why from the official site of the project, in their jar, some functions are not present?

Thanks to all in advance

Francesco

Comment: Considering that even Microsoft doesn't cover all core windows functions in the latest Windows-centric .NET framework, it's not surprising that "JNA.jar" has a number of omissions as well :)

Answer (score 2):

> Q: Where can i find a complete list of all windows dll with a complete
>   list of all functions, and possibly with a compatibily list with all
>   of windows versions? (very important) From msdn site i've found the
>   complete function list with the name of the library where the
>   functions are contained, but not the other.

A: Yes, MSDN library website is the preferred choice http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/default.aspx. But, I don't get it why you cannot find the others. It is completely all there if you know how to search for them. But, some functions may not be easy like COM interfaces which are difficult to be translated properly into JNA version.

> Q: Can i create a new interface that extends Kernel32, so i can add
>   the missing functions? Why from the official site of the project, in
>   their jar, some functions are not present?

A: Yes, it is likely. JNA Win32 platform in the current form only provides basic interfaces to Kernel32 common functions, you may need to add your own for the missing ones.